# Run RDP server on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, remote-desktop, xrdp

What's the best way to run a RDP Server on Ubuntu 12.10?

I'd like to run an RDP server on my Desktop running Ubuntu 12.10 and be able to login from another 12.10 machine using the remote login feature at the login screen.

I've installed xrdp but it doesn't seem to work with unity-3d any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What free Remote Desktop (server) solutions are there?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4096/what-free-remote-desktop-server-solutions-are-there)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

fyi... xrdp by itself uses VNC on the remote desktop/server to really take advantage of xrdp you also need x11rdp which is often is not provided in the software center etc.

I've found and used the following scarygliders tool that automatically downloads & builds the latest/greatest xrdp and x11rdp on your machine and intalls it for you.   It takes a while because of the complexities of building the x11rdp but it has always worked for me.

Then.. with that done.. look into installing guacamole

scaryglider's site:
http://scarygliders.net/2012/05/23/the-scarygliders-x11rdp-o-matic-and-rdpsesconfig-hotness-upon-hotness/

guacamole site:
http://guac-dev.org/

with guacamole installed and with xrdp/x11rdp... all you need for remote desktop on your client is a HTML5 capable web browser.

This works very well together and the HTML5 browser doesn't require any plugins for the remote desktop.

Comment: This is good, it has a `--justdoit` option which takes care of the entire install. It also lets you configure xrdp very easily and allows you to select the interface (Gnome, KDE, XFCE, etc.) and installs it if it's not already available. Good solution to the issue with unity 3d for now.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem this morning; attempting to install on an EC2 Ubuntu 12.10 instance. I solved it thusly...

After installing `gnome` and `xrdp`, install `gnome-session-fallback` (instead of 2d or 3d)

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Then update `.xession`...

```
pico .xsession
```

Add the this line to .xession (remove others)...

```
gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback
```

Exit pico by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and hit <kbd>Y</kbd> to save when prompted.

Restart `xrpd`...

```
/etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

You should now be able to connect with your rdp client...

Answer (score 2):

While they manage to fix Unity with xrdp, I'd suggest to use the gnome desktop, there's a step by step procedure described here:

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3518

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently using that work around, but it's just frustrating that there is only one RDP server software.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at teamviewer.com. I'm just trying it after spending hours faffing around with guacamole and installing x11rdp-o-matic and getting nowhere. It's not the ubuntu-native  solution, but if it works...?

Comment: Teamviewer's a good solution. I use it to support my family it's very nice and a simple solution that I would advise anyone to use if you want an easy install and use setup.

Comment: @siamii That's kind of unfair - RDP is a Windows thing, you would have similar issues getting a remote X11 session up on Windows.