# VNC Server not asking for user-auth

Tags: 12.04, server, vnc, remote-access

I have setup my VNC Server on Ubuntu 12.04 following [this guide](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-VNC.html). It all works fine, but what I would like it to do is upon connection prompt the user VNCing to login. At the moment I am auto-logged on as root and the second I logout I just get a black screen.

What I'm saying is that I wish for it to show a gnome login screen

I have gnome (latest) and VNC (latest) running...

Comment: Check this http://coddswallop.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-complete-vnc-server-setup/

Comment: That only gets me as far as I already am

Comment: Check **Connecting to your login Screen** section at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check xRDP in addition to above.

Details : [Run RDP server on Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226329/run-rdp-server-on-ubuntu-12-10)