# Remote desktop from Windows to Lubuntu

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, remote-desktop

Is there a way to remote connect (via windows remote desktop) to my Ubuntu server which has the Lubuntu Desktop, just like is possible with Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than in Ubuntu the leightweight Lubuntu desktop does not include a VNC server by default. We will have to install and configure a VNC server before we are able to view our Lubuntu desktop remotely.

This can be [vino](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vino) [image: Install vino] (the Ubuntu default VNC server), or any other VNC server (I made good experiences with [x11vnc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/x11vnc) [image: Install x11vnc]). A VNC server can be installed and configured through a SSH session in case you have no physical access to your server.

See also:

- [Ubuntu Wiki: Lubuntu Remote Desktop](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/RemoteDesktop)
- [What free Remote Desktop (server) solutions are there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4096/what-free-remote-desktop-server-solutions-are-there)
- [Run RDP server on Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226329/run-rdp-server-on-ubuntu-12-10) for access via RDP (e.g. from Windows)

Comment: I have no physical acces, it is a cloud server so it has to be via SSH. Does this mean that I need a VNC viewer, and can not use the build in remote desktop on windows?

Comment: See edit for RDP and other solutions in case you do not want to run a VNC viewer in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look here: 
[Remote desktop for multiple users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247115/remote-desktop-for-multiple-users/287371#287371) 
I have added useful information for this too.