# Unable to install FreeNX Server on Ubuntu Trusty. Alternatives?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, remote-desktop, freenx

Trying to install FreeNX-Server on Trusty is always failing with dependency on `nxagent`

```
***root@xxxxx-unix:/Downloads# dpkg -i freenx-server_0.7.3.zgit.140303.1848.e81c1e4-0~ppa2~trusty_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package freenx-server.
(Reading database ... 169875 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack freenx-server_0.7.3.zgit.140303.1848.e81c1e4-0~ppa2~trusty_i386.deb ...
Unpacking freenx-server (0.7.3.zgit.140303.1848.e81c1e4-0~ppa2~trusty) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of freenx-server:
 freenx-server depends on nxagent (>= 2.1.0-0); however:
  Package nxagent is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package freenx-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 freenx-server***
```

Answer (score 13):

FreeNX is pretty old and **unmaintained**.

You should try **X2GO** which uses same NX technology ([1](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:newtox2go), [2](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:advanced:x2goserver-in-detail#x2go_s_serverwhat_is_it_what_does_it_do)) and is actively maintained.

## Server installation

You can find the [detailed guide in the X2Go wiki](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver), the essential commands in 14.04 are:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goserver
```

## Client software installation

You don't have to add the PPA, `x2goclient` is available since 12.04 from the [repository](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/x2goclient/).

Note that X2Go is still [incompatible](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat) with desktops that rely on 3D acceleration.

Comment: How do you start the service up?  when I tried:   x2godesktopsharing
x2godesktopsharing: cannot connect to X server

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team/trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freenx-server
```

Some websites report success using ppa freenx-team/testing (instead of freenx-team/trusty). But that didn't work for me

Comment: This is interesting - at least it almost works.  But where do you get a freenx client for version 3.2 for Windows?

Comment: @slashdottir: You can use OpenNX client to connect to the nxserver: http://opennx.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use gdebi, it should take care of any dependency that needs to be downloaded:

```
sudo gdebi -i <packagaename.deb>
```

If it's not installed, just type first:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```