# How to access Ubuntu GUI through Teamviewer on headless server?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, headless

I'm building what will primarily be a Plex Media Server, but I also like to tinker with Linux, so I'd like to get to the GUI via Teamviewer.

I got everything up and working before I realized GUI doesn't load without a monitor attached.

How can I set up a dummy monitor, or something?  I'm not very good with command line, but can do it well enough to follow instructions.  This box will be running without keyboard, monitor, or mouse.

Comment: Use a VNC serer such as FreeNX or vncserver

Comment: To improve bohdi's very low quality comment, alternatives to consider [Install an NX server like X2Go](http://askubuntu.com/a/466317/40581) or [How do I install a VNC server?](http://askubuntu.com/q/168878/40581).

Comment: You can use also a screen program to display virtual desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The package "xserver-xorg-video-dummy" appears to do what is required

Some details on setting it up in this question

[Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/ubuntu-14-04-add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)

Comment: Nothing I've tried causes X to load the desktop unless there is a monitor plugged in, and I've seen this as an issue everywhere I've searched.  Are you sure about this?

With a monitor attached, I can get to the GUI with Teamviewer.  Without the monitor, nothing shows up on my remote admin computer. It just won't connect.  I can still use Plex, so the computer is running properly and is available on my network.

Comment: Sorry, I found another post that could be worth checking, i've edited

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm headed out of town for several days but will try that series of things.  
Before I do that though, I think I'll make a dummy monitor plug.  I don't know what resolutions I'll be able to use, but it should do the job, even if it is a crude solution.  I'll report back.

Answer (score 1):

I have basically installed a package xserver-xorg-video-dummy with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-dummy` then created a config file named `xorg.conf` with following content:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1366x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I also created two scripts `monitor.sh` and `nomonitor.sh`:

`monitor.sh`:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf
```

`nomonitor.sh`:

```
sudo cp xorg.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

You can execute one of the scripts over the `ssh` or when the monitor is attached.

You will need to execute `sudo reboot` after executing the scripts.

You can execute then `xvnc` or `teamviewer` as you like.

Comment: aparently xserver-xorg-video-dummy won't install after 18.04 update