# connect (e.g ssh) with graphical interface to Linux machine

Tags: ssh, gui

I am trying to connect from my Ubuntu machine at home to my work machine which has Ubuntu too. I know that ssh -X gives the ability to launch graphical interface yet it is not exactly what I want. I always leave my machine at work running many graphical interface applications and I am looking for some thing like remote connection in windows where you connect to the machine and see all running applications and the desktop. For example,Eclipse, MySql workbench, opened tab in chrome, etc.

Thanks

Comment: As a client, [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) seems popular. For the server, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4096/what-free-remote-desktop-server-solutions-are-there).

Answer (score 1):

What you look for is a VNC connection. Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers)! Mainly install a VNC server on the computer at work, and a VNC viewer/client on your Ubuntu machine at home.

Comment: I installed vino. Then when I run   vncviewer localhost:12345 &   on my local I get "Server did not offer supported security type". I tried solution 1 and 2 in (http://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/KB:Fix_VNC_Desktop_Sharing_on_Ubuntu_Desktop_14.04) but still having the same issue.

Comment: I never used vino, I used x11vnc as server VNC and Remmina as client. Try with them maybe, if you got time!